# I forgot my phone PIN plz help?

Tags: locked-out

i forgot my Huawei g6 u10 PIN and i try too much time to open it but i'm not success to open it and i search about forgot-ting password on internet they said press volume up and power button in the same time and thing a logo will ...the logo is come for me and the option is not come me i think there is 4 or 5 option there is saying me(check sd update pkg is exist...make sure USB cable has been inserted!usb update starting...)plz help

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please check our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first aid.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *root access* and *TWRP* on your device it's quite simple:

- You have to boot up into `TWRP` than start the (TWRP's) built-in file manager, **navigate** to `/data/system` and **delete** `password.key` *and/or* `gesture.key` and reboot.

If you have root access but TWRP not installed and you can access to `FastBoot mode` you can boot up into TWRP recovery with this:

- `fastboot boot twrprecovery.img`

But it is just a temporary method.

Or if your device isn't rooted or there is no way to install TWRP on it, you have to hard reset (*HR*) your phone from the original recovery mode* or if you have an active internet access on your device and you activated `ADM` (*Android Device Manager*) you can add a new password to your lockscreen:

1. On a computer or other mobile phone, visit: google.com/android/devicemanager
2. Sign in using your Google login details that you also used on your locked phone.
3. In the ADM interface, select the device you need to unlock (if it isn’t already selected).
4. Select ‘Lock’
5. In the appearing window, enter a temporary password. You don’t have to enter a recovery message. Now click ‘Lock’ again.
6. If it was successful, you should see a confirmation below the box with the buttons Ring, Lock and Erase.
7. On your phone you should now see a password field in which you should enter the temporary password. This should unlock your phone.
8. Now, before you go on with your life, go to your phone’s lock screen settings and disable the temporary password.

*: **If you do this all of your data will be purged, of course security reasons. So it must be your decision.**

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a hard reset? If not, I would recommend trying that via the recovery. If you cannot, try using adb to reset it.

Comment: I think he can't even boot into recovery mode to do a HR. But if his phone is rooted there's another way too.